# Ext GWT - Textarea not scroll to bottom

Tags: gxt

I used com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextArea

```
txtConsole= new TextArea();  
txtConsole.setReadOnly(true);
container.add(txtConsole);
```

and setting its value and trying to set scroll to bottom;

```
txtConsole.setValue(message);
txtConsole.setCursorPos(message.length());
txtConsole.getElement().setScrollTop(txtConsole.getElement().getScrollHeight());
```

But scroll is still at the top of the textarea.
I am using GWT 2.1 and GXT 2.2.1.

What should I do to send scroll to bottom?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution and it works

```
txtConsole.getElement().getFirstChildElement().setScrollTop(txtConsole.getElement().getFirstChildElement().getScrollHeight())
```

According to below description;

> Need to get the element after
>   rendering. getElement() before
>   rendering will return a dummy element.
>   Also getElement returns the wrong one.
>   It will be
>   getElement().getFirstChildElement();